# curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL

Tags: curl, cat, ip-geolocation

I want to bulk lookup [ip details at ipinfo.io](http://ipinfo.io/developers/bulk-lookup) Here is my code. 
`$ cat ips.txt | xargs -I% curl http://ipinfo.io/%/region`

The file "ips.txt" contains three ip addresses each on a separate line:
(1) 8.8.8.8
(2) 8.8.4.4
(3) 1.2.3.4

This resolves only the last ip address. It should give (1) California (2) Colorado (3) Washington. I get the below:

> curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL
>   curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL
>   Washington

If I write ips.txt with only one ip address (for example 8.8.8.8) I get good results. I think there is something wrong with either my text file or the way I am using cat. Can you help me clean my code so that all three ip addresses are resolved?

Per request, here are details of my setup.

```
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-10.0 OFFICECOMP 2.3.1(0.291/5/3) 2015-11-14 12:44 x86_64 Cygwin
$ curl -V
curl 7.45.0 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin) libcurl/7.45.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2d zlib/1.2.8 lib idn/1.29 libssh2/1.5.0
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: Debug IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets Metali
```

Comment: Without knowing the contents of ips.txt we can't do much. What you can do is replace the curl call with a script which does `echo "Trying url '$1'"; curl "$1"` - that will allow you to see which one is failing.

Comment: ips.txt is simply three single lines of three ip addresses 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 1.2.3.4

Comment: If I eliminate any two of the ip addresses and keep only one then the curl works fine and I get results.

Comment: Unable to get the same error. For me, only 8.8.4.4 always returns a blank, the others return fine. What is the output when you run "uname -a", and when you run "curl -V"? Update and include this info in your question.

Comment: check your character encoding of the TXT file and then check the character encoding assumption of the PHP script. Both should be defined  rather than assumed

Comment: @Martin thanks. I checked, everything was ANSI when I got error. Tried in UNICODE, that did not work either.

Comment: @user454038 could it have anything to do with me running this off CYGWIN?

Comment: Thanks for the info. Probably not Cygwin issue because dealing with just text, which should be universal, barring any encoding issues but from what I can tell its not an encoding error it is complaining about a whole URL you are passing it `Washington`. But I don't see `Washington` in input. What about do `cat -A ips.txt` and update the question to include this.

Comment: @user454038 thanks that caught it! It shows the '^M' character at the end of the lines. Command "dos2unix ips.txt" fixed it. If you put it as answer below, I will accept it since you helped me so much.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

So to summarize, as a step-by step for future reference,

Running `uname -A` can reveal what system is being used for example revealing here it is Cygwin.

This leads us to thinking about Windows vs Linux differences.

One of the known differences are windows/dos line endings. This can be revealed, as well as with generally checking all contents of a text file, with:

```
cat -A ips.txt
```

Now if you find it contains `^M` line endings, as it did here, it means the line endings are dos/windows and not *nix line endings (which would show only lines ending with `$`)

To fix this, simply run

```
dos2unix ips.txt
```

Now, if you run your original command with this fixed input file, it seems CURL is happy with it and it works.

Thank you as well MistaGill, I learned about `ipinfo.io` from this post.

Comment: Changing the line ending to LF worked for me (I used Sublime Text)

Comment: Thank you! I had a text file of URLs which I had URI-encoded, but the \r character got encoded as well. Trimming that off made my script run fine.

Comment: also, if you are running dos2unix on a windows share drive, it will fail. So move the text file to you local linux and run the command.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar situation, and a possible quick fix is to add a `-d "\n"` flag to `xargs`:

```
cat ips.txt | xargs -d "\n" -I% curl http://ipinfo.io/%/region
```

This prevents new lines from being interpreted as part of the argument being passed to `curl`.