# Docker Jenkins Image - curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL

Tags: windows, jenkins, docker

I have created the following Dockerfile to create a Jenkins container.
It successfully works on OSX but when I try it on Windows 7, I get the following error when building the container.

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 32.26 kB
Step 1 : FROM jenkins:latest
---> 997d1b2b89a5
Step 2 : COPY plugins.txt /var/jenkins_home/plugins.txt
---> Using cache
---> 632e6f94438c
Step 3 : RUN /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh /var/jenkins_home/plugins.txt
---> Running in a56c01d8afe0
Downloading credentials:1.24
curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
The command '/bin/sh -c /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh /var/jenkins_home/plugins.txt' returned a non-zero code: 3
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM jenkins:latest

COPY plugins.txt /var/jenkins_home/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh /var/jenkins_home/plugins.txt

# Adding default Jenkins Jobs
COPY jobs/unit-test-adapter.xml /usr/share/jenkins/ref/jobs/unit-test-    adapter/config.xml

############################################
# Configure Jenkins
############################################
# Jenkins settings
COPY config/config.xml /usr/share/jenkins/ref/config.xml

# Jenkins Settings, i.e. Maven, Groovy, ...
COPY config/hudson.tasks.Maven.xml     /usr/share/jenkins/ref/hudson.tasks.Maven.xml
COPY config/maven-global-settings-files.xml /usr/share/jenkins/ref/maven-    global-settings-files.xml

# SSH Keys & Credentials
COPY config/credentials.xml /usr/share/jenkins/ref/credentials.xml
COPY config/ssh-keys/id_rsa /usr/share/jenkins/ref/.ssh/id_rsa
COPY config/ssh-keys/id_rsa.pub /usr/share/jenkins/ref/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Does anyone know what the issue maybe? I'm confused as the `plugins.sh`script should be running inside of a build container rather than on Windows.

Comment: Could help if you posted plugins.txt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should check the line breaks in your `plugins.txt` file.  As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768956/curl-3-illegal-characters-found-in-url) the issue may be caused by different line endings between Windows and Mac OS.

Comment: Thanks this worked! The issue was because when I checkout out my git repo on Windows it converted the `plugins.txt` file to *CRLF*.

Comment: I just created a `.gitattributes` file with the following line and this kept it in *LF* format.

    `* -text`